# Creating object using Reflection.Emit in a simple compiler

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

To create instance of a class using `Reflection.Emit` I need to issue `OpCodes.Newobj`, however it requires a constructor of created class. So if I write my own compiler, how do I generate code for a method which creates instance of another class which is defined in a source code (not in a runtime library)?

I do code generation in 2 passes, first I create `TypeBuilder` for each class I have and I add method stubs to them so that they can be referenced during second pass. However I can't call `TypeBuilder.CreateType` for those stubs because I will get an exception, Reflection.Emit requires all methods to be defined and have body. But at the same time I can't finish code generation for a method which needs to create an instance of a class which was defined in a source code.

So, how do I create code for this:

```
class Foo
{
}

class Bar
{
    Foo DoSomething()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo Create()
    {
         return new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be doable with Reflection.Emit, but not all tasks that a compiler might need to do are possible: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2009/11/29/the-limitations-of-reflection-emit.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three passes:

1. create a `TypeBuilder` for each class
2. for each class, create a `MethodBuilder` for each member method including constructors
3. for each class, generate method bodies using `ILGenerator`.  As you finish iterating methods on each class, call `CreateType()`

When you emit `newobj`, you can pass a `ConstructorBuilder` representing the constructor, which means the class and constructor don't have to be frozen yet.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake was that in my test code I was using <code>TypeBuilder.GetConstructor()</code> to get a default constructor and that method needed type to be created first. But I should create my own constructor and pass <code>MethodBuilder</code> as you said. Thanks.

Comment: "you can pass a `MethodBuilder` representing the constructor" Don't you mean `ConstructorBuilder`?

Comment: @svick: Yeah, I thought it was the same, but it's only the `MethodBase` that is shared between constructors and ordinary methods, and the hierarchy branches beyond that.